# JSON object repeated string efficiency

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace

I have a JSON object that contains about 150 entries of the form `[key] : [sentence]` where sentence often contains the same text over and over again. For example:

```
var test = {
    "abc" : "This is the first sentence that is in this JSON object. Hello! Blue."
    "abd" : "Red. This is the second sentence that is in this JSON object. Hi!"
    "abe" : "This is the third sentence that is in this JSON object. Hey! Yellow."
    "abf" : "White. This is the fourte sentence that is in this JSON object. Hola!"
}
```

You can see that the string "sentence that is in this JSON object." repeats quite often. Would it be more efficient to replace it with some anchor and then replace the anchor once I get the entry from the object? That is:

```
var test = {
    "abc" : "This is the first #anchor# Hello!"
    "abd" : "This is the second #anchor# Hi!"
    "abe" : "This is the third #anchor# Hey!"
    "abf" : "This is the fourte #anchor# Hola!"
}

var anchor = "sentence that is in this JSON object."
```

And upon getting the desired value from the JSON, replace the string with the actual text? The sentences don't have a particular pattern but a large number of them contain a repeating string of text. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Just use some compression. Especially since you can't use variables in JSON.

Comment: If your server gzips the output then I wouldn't worry about this kind of optimization.

Comment: More efficient with regard to what? Speed? Memory consumption? Data transfer?

Comment: Probably not more efficient in a decent server setup, but it might be easier to maintain.

Comment: @zeroflagL, was thinking mainly speed (that is, CPU cycles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSON download is gzipped (which is extremely likely) then you probably won't save much bandwith if any. Gzip compression is very good at removing duplicate strings.

To find out, put your JSON in a file, then use any Gzip utility to make a .gz file from it. Do the same with another version of your JSON and then compare the sizes of the two .gz files. You may be surprised how little difference there is.

If you don't have a Gzip utility, get [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Bandwidth aside, you may save memory in the browser by combining strings. Whether that's worth it or not depends on how many strings we're talking about.

Comment: I'm not sending over the whole JSON. Only that one result that I get from the JSON. All the data is on the server and the client only gets one result, not the whole file. Or am I misunderstanding your answer? :)

Comment: What I was referring to is whatever you send down. In your question that appears to be an object containing a number of strings. Could you give a specific example of the actual JSON content that we're talking about? That is, the exact contents of the JSON response.

Comment: From the example above, the response would be e.g. `Red. This is the second sentence that is in this JSON object. Hi!`. Or any of the other values. That is, the object is stored on the server, the request sends a key and the response is the value for that key.

Comment: That's the entire response to the GET request? A hundred bytes or so? There's no benefit to making it any smaller than that. It's all going to fit in a single packet regardless, and really the latency is all that will matter. Making it 25 bytes instead of 250 won't get it into the browser any faster - or at least not enough to ever matter. If you were downloading a *much* larger amount of data, then sure, it would make sense to find ways to shrink it down. But not when it's just a few hundred bytes.

Comment: That's why I'm more concerned about the speed (i.e. CPU cycles) consumed on the server with this structure. Simply said, is it worth having a huge array or a smaller one at the cost of extra computation.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are we now talking about whether it's better to download an individual hundred-byte response each time one is needed, vs. sending down a much larger block of data all at once that has all the possible responses in it, and then just using that data directly when needed? Or are we still talking about whether it's worth it to reduce a 100-500 byte response down to 25-50 characters? It seems like there are two or three semi-related questions in play. Can you clarify exactly what you want to find out, with specific examples?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are talking about trading bandwidth for computation.  In the original case, there is more bandwidth required and no post-download computation (string replacement).  In the latter case, there is less bandwidth but you have post-processing which need to occur.

To me the only way you are going to answer this definitively for your use case is to test the two scenarios and decided what works best for you.  You also must decide if possible tradeoff of bandwidth for execution time is one you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many entries there are this may save some memory or server bandwidth, but I don't think its worth the complexity and processing power needed to reconstruct the sentences.

Either way this is a bad optimization IMO. Use standard optimizations like gzip which naturally handle duplicate strings.

Comment: What is the number of entries replacing would start to be a better option. (right now I have about 100 entries in about 5 JSON objects)

Comment: It would not, the more entries the more string concat on the client side. Either way this is a bad optimization IMO. Use standard optimizations like gzip which naturally handle duplicate strings.